# If an answer recommends a site, and I find the site is not helpful, should I downvote the answer?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

[This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/20727/2509) recommends a particular hostel search engine website.  For reasons I explained [in a comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20726/is-there-a-metasearch-engine-for-hostels#comment32732_20727), I think this is a bad website (not useful, claiming to be complete but has 0 of 4 nearby hostels I know).  That doesn't make the answer bad per se, but it does affect the usefulness of the answer, and should an alternative answer recommend a site that is more useful, I'd upvote that one.  The question is, should I downvote the answer based on the quality of the website it recommends?

Comment: Actually I don't recommend it. I merely list it because it's a hostel meta search engine. I can't recommend it because I've only played with it and haven't tried to use it to actually find a place to stay. But as for voting it up or down I would say that's up to each person who reads it to decide.

Answer (score 5):

Writing a comment (as you did) explaining why you think that link is bad is be the best strategy in order to help. A simple downvote doesn't tell much.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO the answer is helpful and shouldn't be downvoted. Yes, it's probably not the best hostel search engine and has only few hostels listed.
If you don't find the link is useful, just don't upvote it, but downvote would be too hard, otherwise you should upvote the best answer and downvote all other answers as they're less useful.